# Get data from array that has values that are seperated by :

Tags: php, arrays

I have some data in a table that has the data separated by :

What I am trying to do is to create an array of all the table data and then explode  the data that happens to be seperated by :

For example 
My table has the following columns
pid,mid,uid,permissions

Now the data for a row will look typically like this

```
1,2,0,View:Add 
2,3,0,View:Add:Edit 
3,4,0,View:Add:Edit:Delete
4,5,0,View
```

Now I have created the array for the permissions and I get this output

```
    Array
(
    [0] => View:Add
    [1] => View:Add
    [2] => View:Add
    [3] => View:Add
    [4] => View:Add
    [5] => View:Add
    [6] => View:Add
    [7] => View
    [8] => View
    [9] => View:Add:Edit:Delete:Export
    [10] => View
    [11] => View
    [12] => View:Add:Edit:Delete:Export
)
```

However what I ideally want is to be able to explode the data at the :
and then I want to do a little function at this point
So [0] => View:Add 
would give me something like

```
index[0]
View - some other data here
Add - some other data here
index[12]
View - some other data here
Add - some other data here
Edit - some other data here
Delete - some other data here
```

etc - You get the rough idea

However the explode line just gives me an array to string error
See code below

```
$permq = mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT * FROM `permissions` WHERE `uid` = '$_SESSION[userid]'");
$permcheck = mysqli_fetch_assoc($permq);
$allowedmodules = array();
$modperms = array();
$shortnames = array();

do 
{
$short = mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT * FROM `modules` WHERE `mid` = '$permcheck[mid]'");
$permission = explode(":",$permcheck['permissions']);
array_push($allowedmodules,$permcheck['mid']);  
array_push($modperms,$permcheck['permissions']);    
array_push($shortnames,$short['shortname']);
} while($permcheck = mysqli_fetch_assoc($permq));


foreach($modperms as $value)
{
$data = explode(":",$value);
echo $value."<br>" ;
}
```

Comment: You're not using `explode`, but `implode`.

Comment: Edited .. was trying something when I copied the code

Comment: print_r the $permcheck value and check what you are getting

Comment: Is changing your db structure an option?  Because this is ... not optimal.

Comment: When you say for example `View - some other data here`, what do you mean by `some other data here`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want each element of the array to be another array where the elements of that sub array is each value seperated by a `:`?

If so then you can loop through the array and convert each value to a subarray using the `explode()` function as follows:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($modperms); $i++)
{
    $modperms[i] = explode(":", $modperms[i]);
}

print_r($modperms);
```

Did I understand you question correctly?

Comment: Yeah sort of ..
Im basically trying to hide / show <a> elements based on what permissions for each module the person has so if they have view  , add, edit etc permissions for say module 12 ( as per the array dump in original post ) it would show <a href="12/view">View</a>,<a href="12/add">Add</a> etc

Comment: I know what I'm trying to say just cant get words out correctly

Comment: @chris-y And is the module number also in the database? If so, which of the values from your question represents it?

Comment: The module number is in the allowedmodules array
Its the 2nd value so 2,3,0,View:Add:Edit  3 is the module number

Comment: OK so the module id is in the allowedmodules array and then the index value in the modperms array is the module id

Answer (score 0):

if I get what you want (which is not totally clear) here it's

```
$array = Array
(
    "View:Add",
    "View:Add",
    "View:Add",
    "View:Add",
    "View:Add",
    "View:Add",
    "View:Add",
    "View",
    "View",
    "View:Add:Edit:Delete:Export",
    "View",
    "View",
    "View:Add:Edit:Delete:Export"
);

$result = array();

foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
    foreach (explode(":", $v) as $k2 => $v2) {
        $result[$k][$v2] = "some data";
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

Comment: Yeah sort of .. Im basically trying to hide / show <a> elements based on what permissions for each module the person has so if they have view , add, edit etc permissions for say module 12 ( as per the array dump in original post ) it would show <a href="12/view">View</a>,<a href="12/add">Add</a> etc

I know what I'm trying to say but just having issues explaining properly

Comment: @ChrisY that's not in your question; i answer what you asked for.